# How to stream a local video file over Internet using avconv/avserver?

Tags: streaming, ffmpeg, video-streaming, avconv

As FFmpeg is going to be dropped from Ubuntu, it will be important to know how to broadcast videos over Intrnet using **avconv**. An official [guide](http://libav.org/avserver.html#How-does-it-work_003f) is available, but it doesn't give much information how to work it out, step by step...
I have tried several times, but no luck.
Your simple & complete instructions are highly appreciated....!

## Thanks!

Comment: FFmpeg has returned and Libav (avconv) has been dropped.

Answer (score 0):

Using a line like this will get you moving:

```
avconv -f video4linux2 -s 640×360 -r 30 -b 350k -i /dev/video0 -f flv rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/live
```

Where

- -s is your resolution (640×360)
- -r is your frame-rate
- -b is your max bitrate (k= Kbps)
- -i is your webcam or input video stream (your webcam will usually be something like /dev/video0)
- -f flv is the output codec (in this case, we'll use Flash video)

Just replace the "rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/live" without your output URL, and dont forget to add your stream key to the end :)

Comment: `avconv` has been dropped from Debian & Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, but it was in answer to the question.  He asked specifically about `avconv`.

Comment: More than 4 years ago.

Comment: True, but was unanswered.  Thought I'd just pick up an old question and provide an answer.  Interestingly, `avconv` is still in Ubuntu as of 16.04 LTS.  It's just not the tool of choice anymore.  When you install `libav-tools`, it's there.  Right along side `ffmpeg`

Comment: That's a transitional package.

Comment: Yes, but still viable for those of us who still use it.